# difference on unordered_set from boost and standard

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-set

I am trying to use unordered_set from boost and standard for an application, the aim is to find the place, namely, the index of certain elements in this set. There is a subtle difference between the results. The elements in boost are reversed according to this simple program. Where is the problem?

simple 'what-if' code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

//using boost::unordered_set;
using std::unordered_set;
using std::distance;

int main()
{
  unordered_set<int> Set;
  int sz = 10;
    for(int k=0;k<sz;k++)
        Set.insert(k);
  unordered_set<int>::iterator ind_searched = Set.find(8);
  unordered_set<int>::size_type indx = distance( Set.begin(),
                                                 ind_searched );
  std::cout << " Index of element is "
            << indx << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

With boost I get

```
Index of element is 1
```

and with standard unordered_set I am getting

```
Index of element is 8
```

I compile both with

```
g++ sgi_stl_1.cc -I /home/utab/external_libraries/boost_1_48_0/ -std=c++0x
```

Comment: The prefix `unordered` is actually there for a reason. The ordering of those containers is not defined and you should not ever rely on it.

Answer (score 6):

You should not assume anything about the ordering inside any implementation of `unordered_map`, `unordered_set`, their `multi` counterparts or equivalent or `hash_set` or `hash_maps`. Consider the place where an element is stored as completely implementation defined, and prone to change in time. Ordering will not only vary between `boost` and the `C++11` standard, but between different hardware platforms and between different C++ implementations. Any code that relies a certain ordering is flawed. So, yo answer your question

> where is the problem?

the problem is only in assuming some data ordering in an unordered data structure.

Comment: my flaw in thinking is that the elements inserted are stored as the order that they were inserted so now the best option is to use a std::map<int, int> for the elements and the indices while creating the map, then search keys then use the values as indices, I do not see a better option, do you?

Comment: @UmutTabak I'm not sure I understand. It sounds a bit complicated using an extra map. If you care about ordering, then use a vector or a list. If you want fast lookup and insertion, use an unordered_map. Maybe you could explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: well as explained in the original post, the aim is to find the place, namely, the index of certain elements in this set. say 1 7 4 2 are the elements and the index of element 4 is 3 so this is what I would like to do but the elements in the original set are not ordered and they should not be ordered, I would like to find this index and use that to extract the information I need...

Comment: @UmutTabak But why do you need this place. There is no "place", or there is, but it can change during the course of program execution. You find elements by looking them up. There is a mapping between element values and place in the structure, but you cannot know nothing anything about the physical place.

Comment: well ok, this order in this search array does no way change it is an inherent property for a specific input so it is fixed there is no append or shrink on this array whichever container I would like to keep that in it. I need this place to extract exactly the elements in a region of my model.

Comment: @UmutTabak unordered_maps, sets and multi-friends *can* re-hash during runtime, so the physical positions of the elements can actually change. Just beware of that.

Comment: ok then they are not what I would like to have I was thinking that the order of these were the same as I imagine them to be but apparently not, I will do that with std::map, that is the most viable option.